# Comparing NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm designing a dynamic SQL-query that will check a source-table against a target table. I would like to compare the rows of the source against the rows of the target to check for differences.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (KEY INT, COL1 INT, COL2 INT)
CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (KEY INT, COL1 INT, COL2 INT)
```

So i created this statement:

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON B.KEY = A.KEY
AND (B.COL1<>A.COL1 OR B.COL2<>A.COL2)
```

But this only works as long as the values of col1 and col2 are not nulls. 
If table-a col1 is null and table-b col1 is null then i would consider them equal.

I know i can put an ISNULL around my columns, but this is a dynamic query being built up, so i only know the column name not the datatype.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [this approach](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON B.KEY = A.KEY
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT A.* 
                  INTERSECT 
                  SELECT B.* )
```

Comment: What if (although I guess it's unlikely owing to the name) the `key` field is NULL?  `ON (B.KEY = A.KEY OR (A.KEY IS NULL AND B.KEY IS NULL))`?

Comment: @Dems - It isn't (or at least the question only mentions `col1,col2`).

Answer (score 2):

How about IS NULL?

Edit:  Updated query to account for bot h columns being null... getting long and ugly, but working...

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
ON B.KEY = A.KEY
AND ((B.COL1<>A.COL1 OR (A.COL1 IS NULL AND B.col1 IS NOT NULL) OR (B.COL1 IS NULL AND A.col1 IS NOT NULL ))
OR (B.COL2<>A.COL2 OR (A.COL2 IS NULL AND B.col2 IS NOT NULL) OR (B.COL2 IS NULL AND A.col2 IS NOT NULL )))
```

Comment: What if both values are NULL?

Answer (score 0):

If TABLE_A and TABLE_B have same columns. You may try this

```
SELECT  * FROM TABLE_A
EXCEPT 
SELECT  * FROM TABLE_B
```

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing. It needs to return rows where the keys match but one of the other columns is different. This would additionally return rows in `TABLE_A` with no matching key in `TABLE_B`

Comment: Sorry but the tables doesnt have the same columns.. But thanks for your answer